# How to fix sonar issue for "Property value should be valid":

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

When I perform the sonar scan on my project, it says *Property value should be valid* for the following lines of code:

```
HR {
  color: 3c78b5;
  height: 1;
}
```

For `color: 3c78b5;`

It recommends:

```
Update the invalid value of property "color". Expected format: <color>
```

And for `height: 1;`

it recommends:

```
Update the invalid value of property "height". Expected format: auto | <length> | <percentage> | fill | max-content | min-content | fit-content
```

But, I don't think we can apply those recommendations to fix this. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe use # for the color and use px or some other unit for height?

Comment: @takendarkk yeah, never noticed... fixed it. thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your color property is not in the valid format for hex values. See [MDN CSS Color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color).

Your height property is not listing a unit. See [MDN CSS Height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/height) and [MDN CSS Length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length).

So yes you can conform to the listed solutions. Your browser(s) might give the correct output but it can't do anything else but assume what you meant in the CSS as they do not conform the rules.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it this way as @takendarkk said in the comment section of the question:

```
HR {
  color: #3c78b5;
  height: 1px;
}
```